# Test results fail to upload from Jenkins to X- Ray

Tags: jira-xray

My team is uploading cypress test results from Jenkins to X-Ray.  The upload is successful with some test cases, but other results fail to upload with the following error.

> ERROR: Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed!
> Status:503 Response:{"error":"Server Error - Error processing JQL
> batch search results - 400"}

Has anyone seen this issue and what is the cause?

Comment: It's hard to tell; 503 errors happen on the server side. Does it happen consistently if you upload a certain results file? If so, then it may be related to that; if that's the case, if you can share the report, it could help. Nevertheless, I would recommend you report this to the Xray team: https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2

Comment: have you solved this?